# readAsDataUrl converting to octet-stream instead of pdf

Tags: javascript, base64, blob

I am getting a blob data from a RESTFul endpoint and then I need to convert it to base64 string with file type as `application/pdf` however its converting it to `application/octet-stream`.

Here's what my codes does:

```
const getBytesData = () => {
    if (user) {
      getInvoicePDFStringByInvoiceId('129', user.user.token).then((data) => {
        if (data.blob) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(data.blob);
          reader.onloadend = () => {
            var base64data = reader.result.replace('octet-stream', 'pdf');
            console.log('Pdf loaded:- ', base64data);
            setPDFLoaded(base64data);
            return;
          };
        } else {
          console.log('Error happened from API = ', data.error, data.message);
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

Can someone help me understand what could solve this issue?